# Best sorting method for reciving data?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, dictionary

In my program, I will be receiving tuples of data: `(Value, Order)`. I want to sort all the tuples by ascending `Order` in a list or dictionary. I get the tuples one by one in a while loop.

What would be the most efficient way of sorting the tuples? I have thought about sorting the tuples as I receive them one by one, then inserting them into the list or dictionary; or I could gather all of the tuples in one list or dictionary first, then sort them. Which of these methods would be best?

Also, I'm not sure whether a list or dictionary would be best for storing this information, or if there is even a significant difference between using either one.

Edit: I should note that after sorting, I need to produce a string of all the `Value`s.

Comment: This is going to vary radically based on the specifics of your situation.  Try one option, see if it works well enough for your situation, if not, try one of your alternatives.  No option is going to be universally right.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Every sorting method has its pros and cons. But in terms of efficiency, I was wondering if one option would be faster than the other in this situation.

Comment: We don't know enough about your situation to say.  You've told us virtually nothing about your situation.

Comment: What else should I add about it? I felt like I gave all the necessary information, but perhaps that is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be interested in the [`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
 SortedDictionary<string, string> dict = 
        new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
```

As MSDN says:

> SortedDictionary has (...) insertion and removal operations for unsorted data: O(log n)

So it will be faster than adding all tuples and then sorting them with O(n log n) complexity.

Comment: The lookup time for `SortedDictionary` is slower than just a `Dictionary` if I remember correctly. But I'm not working with many tuples (<25), so I don't think the `O(log n)` lookup time will affect me significantly. Is that correct?

Comment: In fact, for such a small number of tuples, difference between both approaches won't be noticeable I believe... But retrieval of `SortedDictionary` is O(log n), while in `Dictionary` it is near O(1) so you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SortedDictionary, and it will do the work most probably faster than you. The type of data structure depends on how are you going to access or query the data

Comment: After sorting, I will need to create a string of all the `Value`s.

Comment: You can use the GetValues method of the Dictionary, and if you get them in order all you have to do is concatenate them as you wish

Answer (score 0):

You can use SortedList or SortedDictionary.
The difference is [explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx).

> The SortedDictionary generic class is a binary search
>   tree with O(log n) retrieval, where n is the number of elements in the
>   dictionary. In this respect, it is similar to the SortedList generic class. The two classes have similar object models, and
>   both have O(log n) retrieval. Where the two classes differ is in
>   memory use and speed of insertion and removal:
>
> • SortedList uses less memory than SortedDictionary.
>
> • SortedDictionary has faster insertion and removal
>   operations for unsorted data: O(log n) as opposed to O(n) for
>   SortedList.
>
> • If the list is populated all at once from sorted data,
>   SortedList is faster than SortedDictionary.
>
> Each key/value pair can be retrieved as a KeyValuePair
>   structure, or as a DictionaryEntry through the nongeneric IDictionary
>   interface.
>
> Keys must be immutable as long as they are used as keys in the
>   SortedDictionary. Every key in a SortedDictionary must be unique. A key cannot be null, but a value can be, if
>   the value type TValue is a reference type.
>
> SortedDictionary requires a comparer implementation to
>   perform key comparisons. You can specify an implementation of the
>   IComparer generic interface by using a constructor that accepts a
>   comparer parameter; if you do not specify an implementation, the
>   default generic comparer Comparer.Default is used. If type TKey
>   implements the System.IComparable generic interface, the default
>   comparer uses that implementation.